# How to add properties to a state, which is an object?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I'm doing a chat application in React Native. I have an array of messages, and each message is an object that I would like to have two properties in: *content* and *hour*. I initialize the *messages* array, as well as the object for storing current message:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState({content: ''});
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

Get the current hour:

```
var today = new Date();
var hour = String(today.getHours());
```

Then some JSX for textInput:

```
<TextInput 
          placeholder="Enter text..."
          value={message.content}
          onChangeText={(input) => setMessage({content: input})}
/>
```

And for Button to send message:

```
<Button
          title="Send"
          onPress={() => {
            setMessage({...message, hour: hour}) // Add the hours property to message object
            setMessages([...messages, message]) // Append 
            setMessage({content: ''}); // Clear the input panel
          }}
/>
```

When I try to print out the message and its hour, the hour property is undefined:

```
<FlatList
          data={messages}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return <View>
              <Text style={styles.messageStyle}>{item.content}</Text>
              <Text>At {item.hour} hours</Text>
            </View>;
          }}
          keyExtractor={message => message.content}
/>
```

Comment: A) `var hour = String(today.getHours());` --> the variable name is `hour` (singular, not plural). B) `setMessage({...message, hour: hours})` ---> here, at `hour: hours` the prop `hour` is set using variable `hours` (plural). Unless `hours` is defined somewhere and populated with some value, I'm going to guess it'll go `undefined`. Also: why do 3 separate `setState` calls? Could we just try: `setMessages(prev => (prev.push({ ...message, hour })));` followed by `setMessage({ content: '' });`. Also, where possible, please prefer `let` and `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: @jsN00b Thank you, it works now with the following setState calls:
`setMessages([...messages, { ...message, hour }]); setMessage({ content: '' });`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the hour but not using it when adding a new message. You could simplify your code, like this:

```
<TextInput 
    placeholder="Enter text..."
    value={message.content}
    onChangeText={(input) => setMessage({content: input, hour:new Date().getHours()})}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works now with the following setState calls:

```
setMessages([...messages, { ...message, hour }]); 
setMessage({ content: '' });
```